# Radiobutton loses values every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

1. There are Radio buttons 'Enable' and 'disable' inside an Update panel (say x)
2. below that, I have 3 radio buttons 'Default' 'Upload Image' and 'Text' (say y)
3. when I choose 'Disable' then 'y' will be hidden. else visible. This much works, no problem here
4. when I choose 'Enable' it shows radio buttons in 'y'
5. from that I choose any of those 3 buttons radio buttons in 'x' looses checked value

Comment: it would be helpful to include your code. People may be able to help more then.

Comment: It would make it easier to answer your question if you post your HTML mark up rather than describing it - the devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a different value for the [RadioButton.GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname.aspx) for each `RadioButton` controls group.

Comment: +1 That's exactly what I was thinking when puzzling through the question. It's probably the right answer. :)

Comment: @Bazzz: Sometimes, it is hard to read a question even if it was written in English !!